# how to fix 500 status err in form submission template using thymeleaf?

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I wrote some code using Spring docs: https://spring.io/guides/gs/handling-form-submission/

I think I made same thing like in docs but my code returns me (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).

Here my code:

FriendListsModel.java

```
    @Entity
public class FriendListsModel {

    @Id
    private Integer id;

    private String friendLists;
// constructor, getters, setters, equal, hashcode, toString (all autogenerated)
```

addController.java

```
 @Controller
public class addController {

    @GetMapping("/add2")
    public String addForm(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("form", new FriendListsModel());
        return "form";
    }

    @PostMapping("/add2")
    public String addSubmit(@ModelAttribute FriendListsModel friendListsModel, Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("form", friendListsModel);
        return "result";
    }
}
```

form.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="https://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head> 
    <title>Getting Started: Handling Form Submission</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Form</h1>
    <form action="#" th:action="@{/add2}" th:object="${form}" method="post">
        <p>Id: <input type="text" th:field="*{id}" /></p>
        <p>Message: <input type="text" th:field="*{friendLists}" /></p>
        <p><input type="submit" value="Submit" /> <input type="reset" value="Reset" /></p>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

result.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="https://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head> 
    <title>Getting Started: Handling Form Submission</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Result</h1>
    <p th:text="'id: ' + ${form.id}" />
    <p th:text="'content: ' + ${form.friendLists}" />
    <a href="/add2">Submit another message</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Logs:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'friendLists' of bean class [com.hoff.blog.FriendListsModel]: Bean property 'friendLists' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?
2022-01-05 20:23:17.347 DEBUG 16504 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Failed to complete request: org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Error during execution of processor 'org.thymeleaf.spring5.processor.SpringInputGeneralFieldTagProcessor' (template: "form" - line 11, col 40)     
2022-01-05 20:23:17.358 ERROR 16504 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Error during execution of processor 'org.thymeleaf.spring5.processor.SpringInputGeneralFieldTagProcessor' (template: "form" - line 11, col 40)] with root cause
2022-01-05 20:23:17.388 DEBUG 16504 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : "ERROR" dispatch for GET "/error", parameters={}
2022-01-05 20:23:17.391 DEBUG 16504 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#errorHtml(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse)
2022-01-05 20:23:17.412 DEBUG 16504 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.s.v.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver : Selected 'text/html' given [text/html, text/html;q=0.8]
2022-01-05 20:23:17.414 DEBUG 16504 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Exiting from "ERROR" dispatch, status 500
```

Comment: A 500 error is a server error. You should check the logs to find out why this is occuring

Comment: what request did you do? Is it the get or the post?

Comment: Try to use another request param something like @PostMapping("/add3")

Comment: @ControlAltDel problem was in my Model, I just changed field name before and forgot to change getter and setter names. I was confused cause VS code doesnt marked it as error in my code, but I got it by reading logs. I'll pay more attention to the logs next time and if will not understand then post them too, thank you!

Comment: Glad your problem is fixed. You can either add an answer to your own question summarizing how this got solved and check that as the answer, or you can delete this question. As for me, I am going to issue a close for on this

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because similar to "needs debuging details", the answer to this question was in the server logs which were not included when the post was first published.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was in my Model, I just changed field name before and forgot to change getter and setter names.